# Image not appearing - Wiley Template

Tags: graphics

I am preparing a journal paper using Wiley's template:

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL,demo]{WileyNJD-v2}
```

and when I try to load a figure by using the command lines provided with the template:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=342pt,height=9pc,draft]{2.PNG}}
\caption{Test\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}
```

the output is a black image without any content:

[image]

Could you help me?

Comment: Remove the option "demo", i.e use `\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}`. When you use the option "demo", graphics are shown as black rectangles. You also have to leave out the "draft" option from the `\includegraphic`, because this option also leave the true graphics out.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sveinung. Your suggestions worked perfectly fine!

Comment: Then I kindly ask you to accept my answer by clicking the green tick mark to the left of my answer. In addition, you should delete your "thank you" answer, because it it not the way things are done at at this site.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the option `demo`, i.e use

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
```

When you use the option `demo`, graphics are shown as black rectangles. Leave out the option `draft` from `\includegraphics`, because the option reserves correct space, but does not include the graphics.

Do not use `\centerline`! Use the command `\centering` inside the figure environment instead.

Try:

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{your other packages}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering       % Use centering instead of centerline"
\includegraphics[width=342pt,height=9pc]{2.PNG}
\caption{Test\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**NB!** I have not tested the MNWE, because I do not know which packages you load, and I do not have the document class `WileyNJD-v2` on my system.

Comment: could we use .pdf in images int his format?